# Remove month and day from date string

Tags: php

I'm trying to figure out how I can remove the Day and Month from this variable as it's looped.  I've tried several strtotime() functions but I can't get the syntax quite right.

```
foreach ( $results as $result) {
   echo $result->date . "<br />";
}
```

Shows dates like this:

```
2014-09-03
2013-09-09
2011-06-01
```

How can I reassign the variable $result->date so that it only shows the Year like this:

```
2014
2013
2011
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Easy way is just to explode date string using `'-'` delimiter and take year element:

```
foreach ( $results as $result) {
   $dateArr = explode('-', $result->date);
   echo $dateArr[0] . "<br />";
}
```

More complicated way is to convert sting to UNIX timestamp using [`strtotime`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strtotime.php) function and then reformat it with [`date`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php) function.

Comment: Hi thanks, this just gives me dashes for the years, my output is:
-
-
-

Comment: Sorry, look at corrected answer

Comment: @BradM I had forgotten the order of arguments in explode function :) You are welcome.

Answer (score 1):

Just use substr:

```
$date = '2014-09-18';
echo substr($date, 0, 4);   // Outputs 2014
```

Answer (score 0):

this can solve your problem

```
foreach ( $results as $result) {
   $dateParams = explode("-",$result->data);
   $result->date = $dateParams[0];
   echo $result->date."<br />";
}
```